# Finding the position of a button. CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a button and I'm using `CGRectMake` to position it like this:

```
btn5.frame = CGRectMake(211, 280, 109, 60);
```

I guess `211` and `280` are the coordinates of the button. So how can I modify that code if I want the button to be near the bottom left corner.

Comment: No, I want to hard code the frame, so positioning it programatically.

Comment: Sounds to me like what you are trying to do is modify the code from a tutorial you found somewhere. Word of advise: DON'T do that. Learn to program properly, otherwise you'll just limit what you can do to the tutorials you have found.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer, so does it still reflect your original question? Also is my answer below what you are looking for?

Comment: @Emilio: On the contrary, taking code from a tutorial and modifying it _to learn what happens_ is absolutely one of the best ways to get a handle on a new language.

Comment: @lulius: I don't agree with that. Using tutorials might help you **if** you already have some programming knowledge. Otherwise, there is just toio much knowledge you won't get from just reading tutorials, and learning what happens just won't be enough.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez it very much depends on the individual ( a mathematician or physician would have the mental tools to learn from experimenting) and their access to mentors. I am in favour of learning from tutorials, starting from small ones, as well as reading code from much better programmers, as journeymen learned from watching masters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The frame of the button defines where it is located on its parent view. So `btn5` will be in the position (x = 211, y = 280) and will have the dimensions (width = 109, hight = 60) if you use this code:

```
btn5.frame = CGRectMake(211, 280, 109, 60);
```

The general expression is:

```
btn5.frame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
```

---

If you want to change the position of the button to the bottom left corner, you can do like this:

```
btn5.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 60, 109, 60);
```

If you want to add some space between the button and the corner, and also change the size of the button:

```
CGFloat x = leftPadding;
CGFloat y = self.frame.size.width - desiredHeight - bottomPadding;
btn5.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
```

---

For more information, check Apple's [View Geometry and Coordinate Systems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5) guide.

Answer (score 1):

In CGRectMake(211, 280, 109, 60) you are defining a frame for your button.

The first two parameters are the x & y coordinates location of the upper-left corner of your button (in the parent view's coordinate system)

The second two parameters are the width and height of your button.

If you want your button in the *absolute* bottom left corner of the parent's view, then you should set the x coordinate to 0 (i.e. 0 pixels from the left edge of the parent) and the y coordinate to the parent view's height - 60 (where 60 is the height or your button).  If you want to leave some margin around your button, then adjust the x and y accordingly.

Comment: How do i find the x and y coordinates?