# what does bounds really mean in CALayer?

Tags: xcode, calayer

I was confused about the property bounds of CALayer,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(18, 18, 154, 154);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

    CALayer *sublayer2 = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    sublayer2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150);
    sublayer2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    sublayer2.zPosition = 10;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer2];
}
```

sublayer2 draw a small 50X50 rectangle in the center of the rectangle of sublayer1,
but it will draw a 150X150 rectangle if this line is commented out:

```
sublayer2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Check my answer to this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9752695/1207152) and consult Apple's [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5).

Comment: It's frustrating for the seniors to keep explaining these things to us, but you really have written a nice piece of code to illustrate the concepts presented in sch's "guide" link. You could add code to reframe, reset bounds, change center, etc., as button actions or with logs to the console showing resulting rects -- that would make an even better illustration. Then you could add your own answer with your conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

after read sch's "guide", I think the behavior is due to the following reason:

1  as metioned in the guide

> The bounds rectangle is expressed in the view’s own local coordinate
>   system. The default origin of this rectangle is (0, 0) and its size
>   matches the size of the frame rectangle.
>   //and this is what bounds really mean!
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> When you set the size of the bounds property, the size value in the
>   frame  property changes to match the new size of the bounds rectangle.
>
> ... ...

so when execute

```
sublayer2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

the frame's size will change to 50X50 automatically,

here CGRectMake(0, 0,..) "0,0" could be any value,because it will not take any effect.

2  because we didn't change anchorPoint ,by default anchorPoint is (0.5,0.5), and its corresponding position is (95,95),  so finally it will draw a 5X5 rectangle whose center is (95,95)

please correct me if I am wrong